# OpenCV & Yocto Project on Variscite Board (Var-Som-Dual i.mx6)

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, yocto

I've got a problem with OpenCV and Yocto (Ubuntu 14.04).

I'm trying to install OpenCV with Yocto on a Variscite Board. I've followed every possible guide on web (this is the best procedure that I've tried http://www.engcore.com/2014/02/building-opencv-2-4-x-for-freescales-i-mx6-bsp-yocto/)... but no one works!

I've created the image files and then I tried to build the project with the command `$CXX test.cpp -o test` (the `.bb` file is correct). The compiler reads the header files (`#include <opencv2..etc..>`) but it stops on the first instruction with error:

```
"undefined reference to cvLoadImage"
```

The same if I try with `imread` (with `imgcodecs.hpp`). I think that the linker can't find the libraries.

How I can solve it? It's too important for me, I'm trying since a month :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question to improve readability. It will help if you try to provide a [mcve] more than just describing your problem.

Comment: This is a linker error. It means that your code is correct, but the libraries you included can't be found during execution. This specific question has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098470/opencv-2-4-2-undefined-references

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV 2.4.2: Undefined References](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098470/opencv-2-4-2-undefined-references)